# Strange directory is prepended to my PATH

Tags: macos, path, zsh

I installed Python 3 using the Mac pkg installer officially distributed at https://www.python.org/ in addition to the Homebrewed Python 3, which I have been using for years.

The reason I installed another Python 3 is that [QGIS require the official Python 3.6](https://qgis.org/en/site/forusers/download.html#), so I myself only use Homebrewed Python 3 on terminal. Thus I want `python3` to refer to `/usr/local/bin/python3`, but it has lower priority somehow.

```
$ which -a python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

This happens with the minimal `~/.zshenv` below and empty `~/.zshrc`.

```
typeset -U path
[ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ] && eval $(/usr/libexec/path_helper -s)
setopt no_global_rcs
```

which results in the following `PATH` configuration.

```
$ echo $path
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin
```

I don't understand this behavior in two points:

1. my `/etc` is shown below and `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin` should not appear in `PATH`.

```
$ ls /etc/paths.d
$ cat /etc/paths
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin /bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

2. stdout of `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s` actually is as follows. `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin` is appended to the rest, not prepended.

```
$ /usr/libexec/path_helper -s
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin"; export PATH
```

Could anybody help me troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've just found a `~/.zprofile` with the following content:

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.6
# The original version is saved in .zprofile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

I don't know when this was created, but it is the obvious reason. I delete it.

Comment: Isn't it a bit uncanny, if files spring into existence without you knowing?

Comment: @user1934428 Actually, my company supplied the Mac and I let one of my colleagues use it for about a month for a certain reason. I haven't confirmed yet, but I suppose `~/.zprofile` was created while the machine was off of my hands.

Comment: Why does this get downvoted? Might be a silly mistake, but is it worth a downvote?

Comment: Don't know, but perhaps because the obvious place for looking for this kind of effects would be to check the Zsh startup files.